# Efficiently search for combinations of list values in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, combinations

I'm iterating over multiple pandas data frames where on each iteration I extract 2 lists.
Then, for each 2 lists combination, I need to find the row in another Data Frame where each combination of all values in the 2 lists appears.

Simplified example:

The df looks like this (any D_val P_val may appear only once):

```
D_val | P_val | D_PCode  
A     | 1     | 25  
D     | 1     | 21  
C     | 2     | 32  
B     | 4     | 35  
D     | 2     | 126  
B     | 1     | 3  
C     | 1     | 312
```

For a single iteration with the following lists -

```
list1 = [1,2]  
list2 = [A,B,C]
```

I expect to get the following list:
    [25, 3, 312, 32]

Explanation:

```
for [A,1] - 25  
for [A,2] - nothing  
For [B,1] - 3
```

etc.

I implemented it using nested loops, but with multiple iterations, large data frame and long lists it takes far too long.

Any suggestions how to efficiently implement it? I'm happy to use other data structures if needed.

Comment: Since your D_P combinations are unique, you could make an index with the concatenation of D and P for that row (A1, D1, C2, etc), use `itertools.product` to get the Cartesian product of the lists, and then use that as a mask for the df. If this makes sense to you I can try expand it into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just using `isin` twice

```
df1=df.loc[df.D_val.isin(list2)&df.P_val.isin(list1)]
df1
Out[211]: 
  D_val  P_val  D_PCode
0     A      1       25
2     C      2       32
5     B      1        3
6     C      1      312
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate all possible values, then use [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
from itertools import product

import pandas as pd

data = [['A', 1, 25],
        ['D', 1, 21],
        ['C', 2, 32],
        ['B', 4, 35],
        ['D', 2, 126],
        ['B', 1, 3],
        ['C', 1, 312]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['D_val', 'P_val', 'D_PCode'])

list1 = [1, 2]
list2 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
lookup = set(product(list2, list1))

mask = df[['D_val', 'P_val']].apply(tuple, axis=1).isin(lookup)
result = df[mask].D_PCode

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
0     25
2     32
5      3
6    312
Name: D_PCode, dtype: int64
```

Or just use isin directly on both columns, for instance:

```
list1 = [1, 2]
list2 = ['A', 'B', 'C']

result = df[df.D_val.isin(list2) & df.P_val.isin(list1)].D_PCode
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
0     25
2     32
5      3
6    312
Name: D_PCode, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a `MultiIndex` problem, and is best solved with `reindex`.

```
df = df.set_index(['D_val', 'P_val'])
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list2, list1])

df.reindex(idx)

     D_PCode
A 1     25.0
  2      NaN
B 1      3.0
  2      NaN
C 1    312.0
  2     32.0
```

If you want a dictionary of the matches, use `reindex` + `Series.to_dict`:

```
df.reindex(idx).D_PCode.to_dict()

{('A', 1): 25.0,
 ('A', 2): nan,
 ('B', 1): 3.0,
 ('B', 2): nan,
 ('C', 1): 312.0,
 ('C', 2): 32.0}
```

---

If you only want the rows that exist, use `intersection` for performantly computating the index of the intersection:

```
df.loc[df.index.intersection(idx)]

     D_PCode
A 1       25
B 1        3
C 1      312
  2       32
```