# Search through two different dataframes and merge them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, combinations

I have the two following dataframes. The combination of type, `P_val` and `C_val` is always unique and `C_PP_val` in df1 refers to `C_val` in df2. I am trying to merge these two dataframes based on type, P_val and C_PP_val/C_val, so I can compare the corresponding extra values (`V_val` and `PP_val`).

**df1:**

```
type | P_val | C_val | V_val | C_PP_val
  A  | 1     | 1     | 25.50 | 1 
  A  | 1     | 2     | 22.30 | 2
  A  | 2     | 1     | 33.20 | 1
  A  | 2     | 2     | 31.10 | 2
  A  | 3     | 1     | 21.40 | 1
  A  | 3     | 2     | 32.60 | 2
  A  | 3     | 3     | 35.4  | 3
  B  | 1     | 1     | 23.80 | 2
  B  | 1     | 2     | 13.12 | 3
  B  | 2     | 1     | 19.30 | 1
  B  | 2     | 2     | 21.72 | 2
  B  | 3     | 1     | 33.30 | 1
  B  | 3     | 1     | 19.32 | 2
  B  | 3     | 1     | 22.50 | 2
```

**df2:**

```
type | P_val | C_val |  PP_val
  A  | 1     | 1     |  35.50
  A  | 1     | 2     |  41.20
  A  | 1     | 3     |  32.10
  A  | 1     | 4     |  37.60
  A  | 2     | 1     |  35.20
  A  | 2     | 2     |  31.10
  A  | 2     | 3     |  25.50
  A  | 3     | 1     |  21.40
  A  | 3     | 2     |  32.60
  A  | 3     | 3     |  35.40
  A  | 3     | 4     |  126.70
  B  | 1     | 1     |  23.80
  B  | 1     | 2     |  13.12
  B  | 1     | 3     |  16.30
  B  | 1     | 4     |  25.12
  B  | 2     | 1     |  19.30
  B  | 2     | 2     |  21.72
  B  | 3     | 1     |  33.30
  B  | 3     | 2     |  19.32
  B  | 3     | 3     |  22.50
```

I tried to filter the *df2* to contain only the rows that have matching rows in the df1 with some methods suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53915239/efficiently-search-for-combinations-of-list-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe) post. If it worked and I got 2 dataframes with same length, I could then just insert the list of `V_val`/`PP_val` as a new column into the other dataframe (as long as they are sorted). However it appears to work only partially.

**For example:**

```
merged=df2.loc[df2.type.isin(df1.type) & df2.P_val.isin(df1.P_val)&df2.C_val.isin(df1.C_PP_val)]

print (len(df1), len(df2), len(merged))
```

**Output:**

```
14 20 17
```

The size of `merged` was not matching my expectations. I tried to check what rows got filtered in the merged compared to `df2` and I found out that it filters only the rows which have `C_val` higher than the maximum value in `C_PP_val` in `df1` and ignores the rest.

```
pandas.concat([merged,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

**Output:**

```
   |type |P_val |C_val |PP_val
3  |A    |1     |4     |37.60
10 |A    |3     |4     |126.70
14 |B    |1     |4     |25.12
```

Any ideas what could work for me?

Comment: This looks like a job for `merge` method. After using you can throw away the unnecessary columns from `df1` from the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge` but the result is not a one-to-one relation:

```
cols = df2.columns.tolist() + ['V_val']
out = df2.merge(df1, left_on=['type', 'P_val', 'C_val'],
                right_on=['type', 'P_val', 'C_PP_val'],
                suffixes=(None, '_1'), how='left')[cols]
print(out)

# Output
   type  P_val  C_val  PP_val  V_val
0     A      1      1   35.50  25.50
1     A      1      2   41.20  22.30
2     A      1      3   32.10    NaN  # no match
3     A      1      4   37.60    NaN  # no match
4     A      2      1   35.20  33.20
5     A      2      2   31.10  31.10
6     A      2      3   25.50    NaN  # no match
7     A      3      1   21.40  21.40
8     A      3      2   32.60  32.60
9     A      3      3   35.40  35.40
10    A      3      4  126.70    NaN  # no match
11    B      1      1   23.80    NaN  # no match
12    B      1      2   13.12  23.80
13    B      1      3   16.30  13.12
14    B      1      4   25.12    NaN  # no match
15    B      2      1   19.30  19.30
16    B      2      2   21.72  21.72
17    B      3      1   33.30  33.30
18    B      3      2   19.32  19.32  # dupe
19    B      3      2   19.32  22.50  # dupe
20    B      3      3   22.50    NaN  # no match
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df1_df2_merged = pd.merge(
    df1[["type", "P_val", "V_val", "C_PP_val"]].rename(columns {"C_PP_val":"C_val"}),
    df2,
    how="left",
    on=["type", "P_val", "C_val"]
)

# Output

    type    P_val   V_val   C_val   PP_val
0   A   1   25.50   1   35.50
1   A   1   22.30   2   41.20
2   A   2   33.20   1   35.20
3   A   2   31.10   2   31.10
4   A   3   21.40   1   21.40
5   A   3   32.60   2   32.60
6   A   3   35.40   3   35.40
7   B   1   23.80   2   13.12
8   B   1   13.12   3   16.30
9   B   2   19.30   1   19.30
10  B   2   21.72   2   21.72
11  B   3   33.30   1   33.30
12  B   3   19.32   2   19.32
13  B   3   22.50   2   19.32
```